# Angular 1.3.3 ng-options issues, worked in 1.3.0

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

With AngularJS 1.3.0, this was working great for me:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setting = {
    active: 1,
    array: [{
      name: 'Small',
      value: 'small'
    }, {
      name: 'Medium',
      value: 'medium'
    }, {
      name: 'Large',
      value: 'large'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="setting.active" ng-options="i as FS.name || FS.value for (i, FS) in setting.array"></select>
</body>

</html>
```

On Angular 1.3.0, I was getting just those three options returned, with the "active" one selected. Now on 1.3.3, I'm getting that empty `<option value="?">` tag.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setting = {
    active: 1,
    array: [{
      name: 'Small',
      value: 'small'
    }, {
      name: 'Medium',
      value: 'medium'
    }, {
      name: 'Large',
      value: 'large'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="setting.active" ng-options="i as FS.name || FS.value for (i, FS) in setting.array"></select>
</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas on how to change change `ng-options` to get it to work correctly again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

Notice that you're using the version of the [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) parameter **normally used for object data sources**, even if your source is an array. Therefore, AngularJS assume it can safely treat it as an object, especially in order to get the keys put in the `i` variable. And it's indeed what is done by calling the internal [`sortedKeys()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/14ff529fbbff46413c0cb451a2f0abbd16b05d5e/src/ng/directive/select.js#L527) function, defined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/14ff529fbbff46413c0cb451a2f0abbd16b05d5e/src/Angular.js#L274):

```
function sortedKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).sort();
}
```

It's not a big deal, arrays can easily be  converted in objects. But if the keys of arrays are numeric, keys of objects are **strings**. Thus, the `i` variable is a string too!

That was not a problem before, because comparisons with the `selectAs` part was not strict, and `42 == '42'`, for instance. But **that's not the case any more** since [this change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9e305948e4965fb86b0c79985dc6e8c59a9c66af) in AngularJS 1.3.2.

### The solution

Besides modifying yours objects to include the numeric key and use it in the `selectAs` part, you've got two simple solutions to go around the problem. The first is to use a string in your model, [as you've suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070042/2057033):

```
$scope.setting.active = '1';
```

The other one is to force the `selectAs` part to be numeric, for example by multiply it by 1:

```
<select ng-model="setting.active" ng-options="i*1 as FS.name || FS.value for (i, FS) in setting.array"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, not exactly sure what the fix was from Angular 1.3.0 to 1.3.3 that caused this behavior.  That said, I did notice that changing the `<select>`'s value in the browser now returns a string instead of an integer ("0" instead of 0).

Changing `active: 1` to `active: "1"` solved the issue, though it's not ideal.

Comment: In angular 1.3.2, a fix was put in to fix issue #9639 and #9949, which was a change to use strict comparison.  When using `ng-options` with the `as` key word, the keys for the array will be strings instead of actual number values.  Hence your change to `"1"` fixed your issue.